# Word for "the ability to understand something without missing context"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Not sure if there is a word for what I am looking for. It is almost something along the lines of like "being able to solve" but it's not really a question or problem you are trying to find an answer to. The closest thing I can think of is "perception", but you aren't really using your senses to understand, it's not something physical that you are able to perceive.

Comment: Do you really mean "without missing context"? That means "with context". I suspect you mean "without context" or "with missing context".

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you may be looking for is [intuitive](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/intuitive). From Oxford:

> Using or based on what one feels to be true even without conscious reasoning; instinctive.
>   *I had an intuitive conviction that there was something unsound in him*